# Related NSManagedObject in NSPredicate

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobject

In my `NSFetchedResultsController` I want to have an `NSPredicate` which only fetches objects with certain relationships.

For example:

I have three subclassed `NSManagedObject`s: `Flight`, `Aircraft`, `Battery`.

Every `Flight` has one `Aircraft`. Every `Flight` can have several `Battery` objects.

So when I am fetching the `Flight` objects, this is something I have tried with the predicate: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"aircraft = %@", aircraftObj]];`

So I only want to fetch the `Flight` objects which are related to that specific `Aircraft` object. This doesn't work, but how can I do this?

Secondly, building on that, the `Flight` has `batteries` which is an NSSet of `Battery` objects. So if I want to do the same as the Aircraft, but filter the `Battery` objects, how would I do this?

Thanks, let me know if I need to explain further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem of "double formatting" your predicate.

You could simply write:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"aircraft = %@", aircraftObj]
```

the same would go for your `Battery` objects (but with the proper `Flight`)

Comment: Not sure I understand. I am fetching `Flight` objects. I also have an `Aircraft` object at hand. So during the fetch, I want to only fetch the `Flight` objects, where the `aircraft` relationship is equal to the `Aircraft` object I have. I've tried as you suggested, but it crashes when creating the `NSPredicate` and says `Unable to parse the format string` in the log.

Comment: Worked it out! I was using an NSString which I then put into the predicate. By putting this erectly into my predicate it side steps the issue. However, what if I want to append more to my predicate? This is why I was growing the string to the final result, then setting the predicate. Thanks though!

Comment: read [THIS](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSCompoundPredicate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on joining predicates